# Bash the function is executed twice

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-functions

The script has traps that execute a function that reruns the host script, but executes it twice.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCK="/tmp/performanceScript.lock"

exec_func () {
#Creando Script de Vida Eterna.

rm -f $LOCK
cd $( dirname '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}' )
echo "Volvio a la vida" >> /tmp/secuancia_performanceScript.log
$( which bash ) performanceScript2.sh &
exit $?

}

secuencia=0

if (set -o noclobber; echo $$ > "$LOCK") 2> /dev/null;
then
    trap 'exec_func' INT TERM EXIT SIGKILL

    while true; do
     echo "El numero es $secuencia" >> /tmp/secuancia_performanceScript.log
     ((secuencia++))
     sleep 1
    done

    rm -f $LOCK
    trap - INT TERM EXIT

else
    echo "ya se está ejecutando: $(cat $LOCK)"
fi
```

seeing the debug, the function is executed twice.

```
^C
++ exec_func
++ rm -f /tmp/performanceScript.lock
+++ dirname '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}'
++ cd .
++ echo 'Volvio a la vida'
++ exit 0
+ exec_func
+ rm -f /tmp/performanceScript.lock
+++ which bash
++ dirname '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}'
++ /bin/bash performanceScript2.sh
+ cd .
+ echo 'Volvio a la vida'
+ exit 0
++ which bash
+ /bin/bash performanceScript2.sh
ya se está ejecutando: 13963
```

Why the exec_func function is executed twice?

Comment: Why don't you produce a minimal script that will still exhibit the same problem? It makes it easier to help you, and in doing that you may discover the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a trap on all this signals:

```
trap 'exec_func' INT TERM EXIT SIGKILL
```

which makes that the `exec_func` on `INT` (ctrl-C) and again on `EXIT` (end of script).

Choose only one (if that is what you need) like `INT`

```
trap 'exec_func' INT
```

Or identify [which signal is being trapped similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256709/9110606) and use a case statement to decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the trap once you enter your cleanup method.

something like this

```bsh
# trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
trap ctrl_c INT TERM ERR EXIT TSTP 

function ctrl_c() {
    trap '' INT TERM ERR EXIT TSTP 
    echo "cleanup"
    echo "bye"
    exit 0
}
```